how to get ripem160 from hashlib to work in python 2
I am modifying a script written in python2 that uses hashlib, the actual call is:
ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
I am doing this in a venv python2.
I checked the /usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py and indeed the ripem library is not listed.
So my question is, how can I get a legacy version that has ripem160 in it to install for python 2?
Or can I replace the hashlib module with a different module that provides ripem160 hashing library?
Thank you.

Helloooooooo.......
